# changing the size of textarea using setsize

Tags: actionscript-3

In actionScript,am trying to change the text area using setSize()here is the code..please help me

```
var prbDesc_txt:TextArea = new TextArea();
prbDesc_txt.text = "Hello world!";    
reportAProblemPopUp.addChild(prbDesc_txt); 
reportAProblemPopUp.prbDesc_txt.setSize(100,100);
```

Here am trying to add the textarea to reportAProblemPopUpmc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
reportAProblemPopUp.prbDesc_txt.setSize(100,100);
```

remove the `reportAProblemPopUp` and just reference it directly:

```
prbDesc_txt.setSize(100,100);
```

Otherwise you need to use `getChildByName()` on your `reportAProblemPopUp` if you want to reference it the way you were thinking of.